# In java, how does referencing a user defined class work when dealing with serialization and reference from another instantiable class?

Tags: java, serialization, reference

I have a class which is serializable, say class "`WriteMe`". This class needs another class to update one of its members. Said class is relatively large, since `WriteMe` is just a wrapper class mostly. We will call the large class "`MegaClass`". Therefore we have something like this:

```
public class WriteMe implements Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private String name;

    public WriteMe(String s)
    {
        name = s;
    }

    public void update(MegaClass m)
    {
        list = m.getList(name);
    }
}
```

The hopeful point in doing this is that I don't want to store `MegaClass` as a class variable like the `ArrayList` and `String` are. I'm hoping by passing it in to a method and **only** using it there where it's **needed**, I will reduce the amount of memory used when creating a `WriteMe`, and **also** reduce the file-size of a `WriteMe` object, if I were to pass it to an `ObjectOutputStream` or similar (so that it can be written to file).

Does "`Megaclass m`" just store a pointer to the instantiation of that object? If so, I would imagine that it doesn't matter if I make it a class variable or not, since an address is just a few bytes or so. Is there any advantage to using the object passed into the method only, as shown above? The other way is to pass it into the constructor and assign as a class variable. Is either way advantageous?

Comment: If you had a field in the class of type MegaClass which was marked as transient, it wouldnt get persisted with the rest of the class at serialization, and when loaded from disk it will be null. You could exploit this to maintain a reference at runtime, and just reassign the field variable after the object is deserialized.

Comment: Firstly, couldn't i just mark the class variable in WriteMe as transient? eg: "private transient MegaClass megaReference;" ? Second, does it matter? If its a reference only, ie: an address in memory, wouldn't it only take a couple bytes in the file? an address is just a hex value, a number.

Comment: Sorry, i misread what you said. The "Second" question still holds though. Isn't it just an integer of some form, referring to a spot in memory?

Comment: When the object is serialized it takes whatever serializable non-transient data is associated with its fields with it to disk. When the object is deserialized, there is no guarantee that an object of the same type will be at the same location in memory, so clearly it needs more than just a memory address. If youre talking about the size at runtime, it wont duplicate the MegaClass object unless its on its own thread.

Comment: Sure. This makes sense. Thank you! One last thing. Is there an advantage to doing it the way i have it written in my question? Or is it better to do the transient class variable way?

Comment: Personally, if the only thing you are using in the MegaClass reference is the list, just parameterize your method to accept said list. This decouples WriteMe and MegaClass. Decoupling is good.

Comment: Very good point! So we have a class "SuperClass" that has an instance of both "WriteMe" and "MegaClass". Inside this class we say something like WriteMe.setList(MegaClass.getList(WriteMe.getName())); ?

Comment: the method signature for update would be public void update(ArrayList<String> newList) { //set our field to equal this list here}

Comment: Indeed. Very helpful and clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark W. suggests, the best thing to do is to separate the use of "MegaClass" and "WriteMe", so that all that is required by WriteMe is the data.

```
public void update(ArrayList<String> newList)
{
    list = newList;
}
```

In this manner, a super class which has a reference to both classes may inquire from MegaClass "What is the correct data?", and pass this information to WriteMe! A bonus of this is that no transient data is needed, nor ANY reference to the MegaClass at all!